# Getting 'Module not found ' error when running nodemon

Tags: reactjs, server, graphql

I want to run my index.js file to access graphql endpoints so i can be able to query the data, access it but i keep getting the ' module not found' error code.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App.jsx';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import { ApolloClient, InMemoryCache, ApolloProvider } from '@apollo/client';
import { ApolloServer, gql } from 'apollo-server-express';
import { typeDefs } from './Schema/type-defs'; 
import { resolvers } from './Schema/resolvers'; 


const server = new ApolloServer({
  typeDefs,
  resolvers,
});


const client = new ApolloClient({
  uri: 'http://localhost:4000',
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
});


ReactDOM.render(
  <ApolloProvider client={client}>
    <App />
  </ApolloProvider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);


console.log('GraphQL server running at http://localhost:4000/graphql');
```

I have tried checking if the file is in the directory where nodejs can find it.

Comment: Did you mean `nodemon`?  Also it would be helpful to cut and paste errors verbatim rather than paraphrasing them.  Importantly _which module_ is not found?

Comment: okay: PS C:\Users\Hlobi Lukhele\mobile-matters-ecommerce-site>
[nodemon] starting `node nodemon src/index.js`


file:///C:/Users/Hlobi%20Lukhele/mobile-matters-ecommerce-site/src/index.js:25
  <ApolloProvider client={client}>
  ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
    at ESMLoader.moduleStrategy (node:internal/modules/esm/translators:119:18)
    at ESMLoader.moduleProvider (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:468:14)
    at async link (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:68:21)

Node.js v18.17.1
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...

Comment: That doesn't say "module not found" it says "Unexepcted token '<'".    Are you using babel to translate your jsx to js or are you using a view engine that supports jsx?  (Looks like something got imported without being transpiled)

Comment: i'm using an engine thats supports jsx....but also when i run npm start it does supoort babel to transalate jsx

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you have issues with importing from `apollo-server-express`. Per the documentation, [this package is now deprecated](https://www.npmjs.com/package/apollo-server-express). You should use `@apollo/server` instead.

On a related note, you are mixing server code into your React application, which will run on the client. These two things should run as completely separate applications. Your error is likely because you are mixing these things, as Node cannot just understand your React code by default.

Comment: i have made two seperted files for schemas and resolver.... the only server code is the one on index.js that calls out the typedefs ,resolvers and the url the server will run on" local host"            

const server = new ApolloServer({
  typeDefs,
  resolvers,
});


const client = new ApolloClient({
  uri: 'http://localhost:4000',
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
});


ReactDOM.render(
  <ApolloProvider client={client}>
    <App />
  </ApolloProvider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);


console.log('GraphQL server running at http://localhost:4000/graphql');

Comment: What I'm trying to say is that you are mixing two applications into one. React will be running in the browser (client), while Apollo Server should be running in a Node.js environment (server). It appears odd that you have both of these things in not just the same application, but also in the same file??? What's the idea behind that?

Comment: I really cannot answer the idea behind that, but i've been using following a course steps that were including thier apollo code into their react code and it seemed to be working using mock data... but when i try to run mine in my side the server is not responding and now i'm getting way more error. i would appreciate if you can share links of documentations of anyting of how i can solver ther error

Comment: I'm not sure where things have gone wrong in your tutorial. Does it use something like Vite or create-react-app as part of the setup? The JSX syntax needs to be transpiled by e.g. Babel, as others have discussed in the comments. Can you include your package.json in the original question, please? And also the index.js file?

Answer (score 0):

check all the following packages installed with npm

`@apollo/client,apollo-server-express`

and `nodemon` as dev dependency